# Need help w/ JSONPath

Tags: jsonpath

I'm new to JSONPath and am having some difficulty getting the right syntax to the element that I need. I'm working with responses from the Census Bureau, and the typical response I get is:

```
{
results: [
{
layerId: 0,
layerName: "Census Tracts",
displayFieldName: "BASENAME",
value: "2105",
attributes: {
MTFCC: "G5020",
OID: "20790282931526",
GEOID: "42091210500",
STATE: "42",
COUNTY: "091",
TRACT: "210500",
BASENAME: "2105",
NAME: "Census Tract 2105",
LSADC: "CT",
FUNCSTAT: "S",
AREALAND: "3379105",
AREAWATER: "0",
STGEOMETRY: "Polygon",
CENTLAT: "+40.0836945",
CENTLON: "-075.1929315",
INTPTLAT: "+40.0836945",
INTPTLON: "-075.1929315",
OBJECTID: "48987"
}
}
]
}
```

I need the "TRACT" element, but I cannot get the format right.  I'm grabbing the 'value' element with

```
$.results[0].value
```

But I need the TRACT element as well.  Is there a tool like Xmplify that would give me the JSONPaths for a particular element?

Thanks all.

Comment: $.results[0].attributes.TRACT

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "TRACT" values by using path `$.results[*].attributes.TRACT`. To test your Jsonpath you can use the utility app at http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/.

For more information, you can refer the documentation at https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath